# Third-party ros messages

Tags: ros, c++, java, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to write a standalone C++ or Java program that can prompt you for a text for example and then send it as a ROS message which will be received by a listening ros node?
By standalone I mean that it is possible to compile the program on any machine with no need to ros installed, just using the necessary ros libraries.
Did somebody already do that? I don't really understand how ros internally works and any help on how to collect the needed libraries for that would be very appreciated.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142156/third-party-ros-messages/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-20**:
As a very last resort, you can just implement the ROS network protocol. I would not recommend that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also found something called ros_bridge which looks vers interesting but i didn't test it yet as I already have a working solution thanks to demmeln.

You can check it here:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-04-02**:
Rosbridge works perfectly and I use it now to publish and subscribe to topics. It is very useful and you can implement a control interface for a robot using any programming languages supporting web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on what you mean by ROS installed? You don't *need* to use catkin to compile your node, but at the very least you need a few libraries and header files "installed" or shipped with your project such that they are avaiable for the compiler. And possibly you need to also ship the generated message header files if you don't have the message generation machinery 'installed'. Jonathan Bohren has some excellent tutorials discussing how to compile a very simple example c++ node step by step with a plain Makefile, using pkg-config manually, with a plain CMakeFile and then catkin. Maybe this helps to understand better how everything ties together: http://jbohren.com/articles/gentle-catkin-intro/

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-03-20**:
Thank you very much!! I will check this out.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-21**:
Sure, feel free to open a new question if it is still unclear after reading the tutorial.